# Redirecting Javascript window.print

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to redirect Javascript window.print output to a web service or to a DWR remote method without having to install anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can override, in some browsers, `window.print` with a custom function.

A webpage cannot act as a printer driver though.